# A combinatorial Identity considering Arithmetic Geometric Mean

Tags: combinatorics

I met the following combinatorial identities following *the footsteps of Gauss* in Borwein and Borwein's *Pi and AGM* (p.6); i.e. trying to prove the eq. (1.2.5) on this page.

Prove that

$$\binom{2k-1}{k}^2= \sum^{2k}_{j=1}(-1)^j4^{2k-j}\binom{2j-1}{j}^2\binom{2k+j -1}{2j-1},$$

and also

$$4\binom{2k-1}{k}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}(-1)^{j+1}4^{2k-j+1}\binom{2j-1}{j}^2\binom{2k+j}{2j-1}.$$

These equations are true by experiment, but I am not able to give a proof. Thankful for any help. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If you take the first sum, and write is as an hypergeometric series, it becomes $$(-1)(2k)4^{2k-1} {}_3F_2\left(\left. \begin{array}{c} 1-2k, 1+2k, \dfrac 32 \\2, 2\end{array} \right| 1\right)$$

This sum is a special case of ${}_3F_2\left(\left. \begin{array}{c} a, 2-a, c \\e, 2c-3+e\end{array} \right| 1\right)$. This last hypergeometric series is contiguous to Whipple's identity, which is well known. You should google "contiguous Whipple identity" for more. Some articles will give you what you're looking for.

I didn't try the second sum, but I'm sure it'll simplify to a known result using hypergeometric series.

Comment: Series using binomial coefficients may look different, but writing them as hypergeometric series gives usually a unique expression. Good luck.

Comment: I found it: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-49-179/S0025-5718-1987-0890268-1/S0025-5718-1987-0890268-1.pdf. Thx again.